# blackboard-bold/double-struck capital greek letters

Tags: greek, mathbb

I am trying to show blackboard bold capital greek letters in a document. Font is standard serif font. Math is straight not italic. I made countless attempts based on SE solutions, to no avail. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for mathbb command
\usepackage[symbolgreek]{mathastext} % if you remove this it is even worst
\begin{document}
$a b c \gamma \delta \pi A B C \Gamma \Delta \Pi \mathbb{A B C \Gamma \Delta \Pi}$
\end{document}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you mean these, ℼℽℾℿ⅀, or any Greek? What would bold signify?

Comment: Can you use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX? `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}` works for everything for me except the bb `\Delta`. Not sure why that's missing; doesn't seem to be in unicode.

Comment: My misubderstanding: 'bb' means 'blackboard bold', not 'blackboard'. @frabjous: no bb Delta or delta: "5.4.2 Double-struck The double-struck style (also known as ‘blackboard bold’) consists of upright Latin letters {–,ℤ}, numerals –, summation symbol ⅀, and four Greek letters only: {ℽℼℾℿ}."

Comment: Not a duplicate but similar in what is wanted; this may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661388

Answer (score 4):

Unicode, and therefore `unicode-math` supports three blackboard-bold Greek letters, ℽ (`\Bbbgamma`), ℾ (`\BbbGamma`) and ℿ (`\BbbPi`).

However, with `unicode-math`, if you can find a suitable Greek double-struck OpenType or TrueType font, you can declare it as a math alphabet.with, e.g.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfontface\mathbbgreek{Some Outline Greek Font}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

This lets you write

```
$\mathbbgreek{\mupTheta}$
```

One package that supports this for legacy TeX is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}

\begin{document}
\( \mathbb{\Theta\Phi\Gamma} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: mathbbol sample]

Answer (score 3):

A sort of `bb` for Greek could be emulated:

[image: bb emul]

(My screen image is rasterizing; the PDF is OK.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\bbg}[1]{%
\ooalign{$#1$\cr\raisebox{-.2pt}{$#1$}\cr\raisebox{.2pt}{$#1$}\cr\textcolor{white}{$\mkern0.2mu#1$}}%
}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{D}$\ooalign{$\mathbb{D}$\cr$\mkern0.5mu\mathbb{D}$}

$\Delta$\ooalign{$\Delta$\cr\raisebox{-.2pt}{$\Delta$}\cr\raisebox{.2pt}{$\Delta$}\cr\textcolor{white}{$\mkern0.2mu\Delta$}}
\bbg{\delta}

\bbg{\Phi}\bbg{\kappa}\bbg{\Xi}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Altering Petr Olsak's [faked bold](https://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#fakebold) trick slightly may suit your needs:

```latex
\def\doublestroke#1{\pdfliteral{1 Tr .3 w}#1\pdfliteral{0 Tr 0 w}}

\[ \doubestroke{\Phi \Gamma \Delta} \]
```

[image: fakebold Greek letters]

What this does is simply strokes the letters without filling them (a list of possible values for `Tr` can be found in section 5.2.5 of Adobe's PDF reference, page 402). You may wish to alter the value `.3` to your liking (increase for a heavier stroke).

It's worth noting that this macro will also work with identical results outside of math mode.

Answer (score 2):

Is this suits for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for mathbb command
\usepackage[symbolgreek]{mathastext} % if you remove this it is even worst
\usepackage[copies]{contour}%
\contourlength{1pt}%
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\outline}[1]{\color{white}\contour{black}{#1}}%
$\outline{$a b c \gamma \delta \pi A B C \Gamma \Delta \Pi$} 
\mathbb{A B C} \outline{$\Gamma \Delta \Pi$}$
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]