# mathbbol displays incorrect symbols

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsfonts

I tried to follow the suggestion in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234451/loading-amsfonts-after-mathbbol-does-not-reset-mathbb) regarding how to use blackboard bold symbols for both Greek and Latin letters in the same document.

Bizarrely, I find that when I use the suggested code in my preamble, commands like `\mathbb{\Delta}` and `\mathbb{\Sigma}` result in symbols completely unrelated to the desired ones.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}

\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbl}{bbold}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{\Delta}$

$\mathbb{\Sigma}$

\end{document}
```

generates the output

[image]

I see the same problem compiling on my own computer, and compiling on Overleaf. Does anyone have suggestions for how to fix this? As in the question linked above, my goal is to use the AMS blackboard bold font for Latin letters and the bbgreekl font for capital Greek letters. In other words, my goal is to use

[image: blackboard bold N]

and

[image: blackboard bold Delta]

in the same document.

Comment: Why not using `mathbbol`'s font for all blackboard bold symbols?

Comment: The mathbbol version of $\mathbb{N}$ is rather unusual and ugly (it's sans serif, for one thing). This was essentially the reason for the discussion at the linked question.

Comment: I just found an alternative way to achieve my endgoal, using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495/788). I'm curious what is causing the strange behavior above, but maybe it is moot.

Comment: the behaviour you show is what I'd expect: you are selecting a font that has no Greek and then using commands for Greek, so you get whatever symbol is in that slot.

Comment: The situation is similar to what I've explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281200/82917

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a math symbol font as `\mathbbl`, so you can just change those calls to

```
$\mathbbl{\Delta}$

$\mathbbl{\Sigma}$
```

and the double-struck Greek that you want should result.

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting from David Carlisle's comment to prevent the question from staying unanswered: "The behaviour you show is what I'd expect: you are selecting a font that has no Greek and then using commands for Greek, so you get whatever symbol is in that slot."